# Polymorphic Data Families in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to define a data family that supports polymorphism for explicitly uninstantiated cases:

```
data family Foo a

-- handles some specific case
data instance Foo Int = CreateInt Int Int String

-- handles all other cases
data instance Foo bar = CreateBar bar
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This seems to be strictly related, if not a duplicate, to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433716/why-cant-we-define-closed-data-families

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a closed type family. [Unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49436255/745903), this requires an extra newtype wrapper:

```
newtype Foo a = CreateFoo {getFoo :: Foo' a}

type family Foo' a where
  Foo' Int = IntFoo
  Foo' bar = Barbar bar

data IntFoo = CreateInt Int Int String
data Barbar bar = CreateBar bar
```

Comment: Thanks, just a small remark: Foo Int = IntFoo should be Foo' Int = IntFoo. Same with bar. SO does not allow me to fix this as it's less than 6 symbols.. :)